# CsvHelper space between quotes

Tags: csvhelper

I'm parsing a csv file that looks like this:
"Header1","header2"
"Field1", "field2"

Im getting an exception due to the space after the comma.

I wanted to ask if there is a way/configuration to not get an exception and to parse the field correctly? Field1 under header1 and so on..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Josh Close.  The answer is pretty simple, just add `TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim` to the configuration.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("\"Header1\",\"Header2\"\n\"Field1\", \"field2\""))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();      
    }   
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Header1 { get; set; }
    public string Header2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks! It might help but the I would really want a better way to do it.. Hope it is possible :)

Comment: You can set `TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim` in the configuration.